# Disable TestNG tests based on condition and test class annotation

Tags: java, testng

I have a test suite that from time to time needs to be used on prod environment, but due to technical details it is not possible to run some tests on it. My idea is to annotate such test classes with custom annotations and then disable test methods in them if i'm running against prod. Something  like this:

```
    @DisableOnProd
    class SomeTestClass {   
    @BeforeMethod
    void setUp(){
        ...
    }   
    @Test
    void test() {
        ...
    }   
}
```

I can get something close by implementing IAnnotationTransformer2 like this, but it will disable all test methods:

```
    @Override
    public void transform(ITestAnnotation iTestAnnotation, Class aClass, Constructor constructor, Method method) {
    if (method.isAnnotationPresent(Test.class) || method.isAnnotationPresent(BeforeMethod.class)) {
        iTestAnnotation.setEnabled(false);
    }
}
```

}

Is there any way to get test class annotations to check the condition or there is a way to get the same result with other solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the answers, they've pointed me to the right direction. So far most flexible solution I've got is by using listener that implements IMethodInterceptor:

```
public class SkipOnProductionListener implements IMethodInterceptor {

    public List<IMethodInstance> intercept(List<IMethodInstance> list, ITestContext iTestContext) {
        if (isProduction()) {
            list.removeIf(method -> method.getMethod().getRealClass().isAnnotationPresent(SkipIfOnProd.class));
            list.removeIf(method -> method.getMethod().getConstructorOrMethod().getMethod().isAnnotationPresent(SkipIfOnProd.class));
        }
        return list;
    }

    private boolean isProduction() {
        //do some env determination logic here
        return true;
    }

}
```

This way I can place the annotation either on class and skip all test methods, or just individual methods.

Answer (score 2):

You can use testng listener **onTestStart** with some condition as mentione below:

```
public class TestListener extends TestListenerAdapter {



      public void onTestStart(ITestResult arg0) {

            super.onTestStart(arg0);



            if (condition)  {

                  throw new SkipException("Testing skip.");

            }



      }

}
```

or Before method with some condition can be utilized

```
@BeforeMethod
public void checkCondition() {
  if (condition) {
    throw new SkipException("Skipping tests .");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try cheking annotation present on class along with other condition. For example:

```java
   if(someCondition && testMethod.getDeclaringClass().isAnnotationPresent(DisableOnProd.class)) {
            iTestAnnotation.setEnabled(false);
   }
```